# Strange grafical artifacts while re-inserting widgets into gridlayout

Tags: python, pyqt5, visual-glitch, qgridlayout

I am working on a pyqt5 YouTube-downloader-kindof app using pytube.

To pre-sum up the problem: After deleting a widget from a gridlayout and reinserting others, the texts in that reinserted object have somewhat of grafical glitches (it looks like multiple texts overlap eachother)

SideNote:
Before I came up with this approach I tried to achieve the same dynamic "inserting and removing widgets" on the fly system with QListView or QListModel and ItemDelegates but in both at some point a ran into a brick wall where I either didn't understood how to fix the occurring problems or the qt itself didn't allow for what I was trying.

The details:

To use pytubes functions and arrange them in a nice fashion, I created a new class QYTVidItem which inherits from QWidgets.

```
class QYTVidItem(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QYTVidItem, self).__init__(parent)
                
        self.vid_layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vidDetailLayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vidHeaderLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vidSpecsLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vidStartEndLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.buttonLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()

        self.title = ""
        self.url = ""

        self.defaultThumbPix = qtg.QPixmap(":/assets/default.png")

   def setData(self,purl):
        #debug
        print("setdata for: {}".format(purl))

        self.url = purl.strip()

        errTxt = self.checkLink(purl)         
        if (errTxt != "OK"):
            return errTxt
        
        # load Youtube vid infos         
        yt_vid = YouTube(url=purl)
        
        #debug
        print("Url Found. Title:{}".format(yt_vid.title))
        self.title = yt_vid.title
                
        thumbNail_url = yt_vid.thumbnail_url        
        thumbPixmap = qtg.QPixmap()
        try:
            request = urllib.request.Request(thumbNail_url)
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
            data = response.read()        
            thumbPixmap.loadFromData(data)                      
        except Exception:
            self.thumbPixmap.load(":/assets/default.png")
                
        ##left Side:
        # Thumbnail of video (or default if no thumb is found)
        icoLabel = qtw.QLabel()        
        icoLabel.setPixmap(thumbPixmap.scaled(150,150,aspectRatioMode=qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.vid_layout.addWidget(icoLabel)

        ##right side
        # most upper row: 
        # title
        title = qtw.QLabel(yt_vid.title) 
        self.vidHeaderLayout.addWidget(title) 

        pixmap_remove = qtg.QPixmap(":/assets/cancel.svg")        
        icon_remove = qtg.QIcon(pixmap_remove.scaled(50,50,aspectRatioMode=qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))        
        self.btn_remove = qtw.QToolButton()
        self.btn_remove.setIcon(icon_remove)            
        self.vidHeaderLayout.addWidget(self.btn_remove)  

        self.vidDetailLayout.addItem(self.vidHeaderLayout)

        # Mid upper row:
        # Video Specs
        dur_time = yt_vid.length
        duration = qtw.QLabel("Duration: {} sec".format(dur_time))        
        self.vidSpecsLayout.addWidget(duration)   

        self.vidDetailLayout.addItem(self.vidSpecsLayout)

        # mid lower row:
        # Start/End Marker
        self.vidStartEndLayout.setContentsMargins(5,0,5,0)
        self.vidStartEndLayout.setSpacing(10); 
        self.vidStartEndLayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft)        
        
        #info: i use a double slider from the range_slider package
        slider = RangeSlider(qtc.Qt.Horizontal)        
        slider.setMinimumHeight(10)
        slider.setMaximumWidth(200)
        slider.setMinimum(0)
        slider.setMaximum(dur_time)
        slider.setLow(0)
        slider.setHigh(dur_time)
        slider.setTickPosition(qtw.QSlider.TicksBelow)
        slider.sliderMoved.connect(self.updateSliderVal)
        
        slider.show()   
        slider.raise_()        
        self.vidStartEndLayout.addWidget(slider)
                
        vid_start_txt = qtw.QLabel("start at(sec):")        
        vid_start_txt.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft|qtc.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.vidStartEndLayout.addWidget(vid_start_txt)

        lowVal = slider.low()
        self.vid_start = qtw.QLabel(str(lowVal))        
        self.vid_start.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft|qtc.Qt.AlignVCenter)        
        self.vidStartEndLayout.addWidget(self.vid_start)

        vid_end_txt = qtw.QLabel("end at(sec):")        
        vid_end_txt.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft|qtc.Qt.AlignVCenter) 
        self.vidStartEndLayout.addWidget(vid_end_txt)

        highVal = slider.high()
        self.vid_end = qtw.QLabel(str(highVal))   
        
        self.vidStartEndLayout.addWidget(self.vid_end)
        self.vidStartEndLayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft|qtc.Qt.AlignVCenter) 
        self.vidDetailLayout.addItem(self.vidStartEndLayout)

        # lower row:
        # Video specific Buttons (picograms)        
        self.buttonLayout.setSpacing(10); 
        self.buttonLayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft)
        
        pixmap_play = qtg.QPixmap(":/assets/play2.svg")        
        icon_play = qtg.QIcon()
        icon_play.addPixmap(pixmap_play.scaled(50,50,aspectRatioMode=qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        btn_play = qtw.QToolButton()
        #btn_play.setPixmap(pixmap_play.scaled(25,25,aspectRatioMode=qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        btn_play.setIcon(icon_play)   
        btn_play.clicked.connect(self.playItem)     
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(btn_play)       

        pixmap_stop = qtg.QPixmap(":/assets/stop2.svg")        
        icon_stop = qtg.QIcon()
        icon_stop.addPixmap(pixmap_stop.scaled(50,50,aspectRatioMode=qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        btn_stop = qtw.QToolButton()
        #btn_stop.setPixmap(pixmap_stop.scaled(25,25,aspectRatioMode=qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        btn_stop.setIcon(icon_stop)    
        btn_play.clicked.connect(self.stopItem)             
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(btn_stop)    

        pixmap_download = qtg.QPixmap(":/assets/download.svg")        
        icon_download = qtg.QIcon()
        icon_download.addPixmap(pixmap_download.scaled(50,50,aspectRatioMode=qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        btn_download = qtw.QToolButton()        
        btn_download.setIcon(icon_download)    
        btn_download.clicked.connect(self.downloadItem)             
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(btn_download)  
        
        self.vidDetailLayout.addItem(self.buttonLayout)
        
        #assamble Layouts and activate it
        self.vid_layout.addItem(self.vidDetailLayout)        
        self.setLayout(self.vid_layout)
    
        return errTxt

    def updateSliderVal(self,low_value, high_value):
        self.vid_start.setText(str(low_value))
        self.vid_end.setText(str(high_value))
```

To display this widgets i generate them by inserting an url into a line-edit, create a new QYTVidItem and feed the url into its setData-Function.

```
def insertUrl(self):
        self.main_window.insert_url_msg.setText("")
        if (self.main_window.lineEdit_url.text() == ''):
            return
        else:            
            newUrl = self.main_window.lineEdit_url.text()  
            #check in ordered dict if url allready is in the grid
            if newUrl.strip() in self.ytVidODict:
                self.main_window.insert_url_msg.setText("Error: URL allready loaded")
                return
            
            #Test URL: Rick Roll https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lrj2Hq7xqQ8      
            #Test URL2: BudS&TerH - Lala Remix: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lL7jwhWAU_k       
            
            #parent of each QYTVidItem is a scroll area which contains a gridlayout
            item = QYTVidItem(self.main_window.scrollA)              
            returnCode = item.setData(newUrl)            
            if (returnCode == "OK"):                
                row = self.main_window.url_scroller_grid.count()
                col = 0
                self.main_window.url_scroller_grid.addWidget(item,row,col,1,1)
                #debug to test title text
                gridItem = self.main_window.url_scroller_grid.itemAt(row).widget()
                print("Gridpos: {} ; Title: {}".format(row, gridItem.title))

                #save in OrderedDict:                
                item.btn_remove.clicked.connect(partial(self.removeYTVid,newUrl))
                self.ytVidODict[newUrl.strip()] = item
            else:
                self.main_window.insert_url_msg.setText(returnCode)
                      
            self.main_window.lineEdit_url.setText("")
```

To this point the code just works fine. It creates the widgets and adds them to the gridlayout of the scroll area.

With both Test urls it looks like this:

[image: After inserting two example links]

The problem occures when i use the following delete item function:

```
    def removeYTVid(self,url):
        #debug
        print("remove Triggered by {}".format(url))            
        
        #remove from Scrollarea -> this automaticly causes the remaining items to re-arrange their indexes in the gridlayout
        for vidItem in self.ytVidODict:
            #debug
            print("url: {}".format(vidItem))
            print("vid: {}".format(self.ytVidODict[vidItem].title))
            if vidItem == url.strip():
                self.ytVidODict.pop(url.strip())
                #debug
                print("poped: {}".format(url.strip()))
                break            
        
        #after poping the to be deleted item from the ordered dict, reverse removing all child-widgets
        for i in reversed(range(self.main_window.url_scroller_grid.count())): 
            widgetToRemove = self.main_window.url_scroller_grid.itemAt( i ).widget()
            # remove it from the layout list
            self.main_window.url_scroller_grid.removeWidget( widgetToRemove )

        # re-populate the gridlayout by iterating through the ytVid-Items in the ordered dict
        for vidItem in self.ytVidODict:         
            row = self.main_window.url_scroller_grid.count()
            col = 0
            self.main_window.url_scroller_grid.addWidget(self.ytVidODict[vidItem],row,col,1,1)
            #debug
            gridItem = self.main_window.url_scroller_grid.itemAt(row).widget()
            print("Gridpos: {} ; Title: {}".format(row, gridItem.title))
```

In its core this works fine in that it removes the deleted item from the grid and the ordered dict but after re-inserting the remaining items, the ytviditems show strange grafical articats in the texts (like in this picture).

Error grafical artifacts in the text:

[image: Error grafical artifacts in the text]

I allready tried debugging all texts in between all steps but always ended up with perfectly fine texts.
This artifacts also persist if I clear all items in the gridlayout (by deleting all of them with the button). Noteworthy is that after a full clear it doesn't matter what the next URL is, it will have those artifacts in the texts.

Can somebody explain this phenomenon and how to avoid it?
I thought of possibly having to trigger a re-rendering of a layout or something like thaat.

Edit:
Here is a minimal running version of the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc

from pytube import  YouTube
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout,  QVBoxLayout, QLabel

from collections import OrderedDict
from functools import partial

import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(388, 255)
        self.centralwidget = qtw.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.widget = qtw.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(qtc.QRect(20, 10, 361, 241))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout = qtw.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.lineEdit_url = qtw.QLineEdit(self.widget)
        self.lineEdit_url.setObjectName("lineEdit_url")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_url)
        self.insertUrl = qtw.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.insertUrl.setObjectName("insertUrl")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.insertUrl)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.scrollA = qtw.QScrollArea(self.widget)
        self.scrollA.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollA.setObjectName("scrollA")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = qtw.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(qtc.QRect(0, 0, 357, 206))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout_scroller = qtw.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_scroller.setObjectName("gridLayout_scroller")
        self.scrollA.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollA)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        qtc.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = qtc.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.insertUrl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
    
class QYTVidItem(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QYTVidItem, self).__init__(parent)
                
        self.vid_layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vidDetailLayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vidHeaderLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vidSpecsLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.vidStartEndLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.buttonLayout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()

        self.title = ""
        self.url = ""
       
    def setData(self,purl):       
        self.url = purl.strip()

        errTxt = "OK"         
                
        # load Youtube vid infos         
        yt_vid = YouTube(url=purl)       
        
        self.title = yt_vid.title
                
        ##left Side:
        # Thumbnail of video (or default if no thumb is found)
        thumbNail_url = yt_vid.thumbnail_url        
        thumbPixmap = qtg.QPixmap()
        try:
            request = urllib.request.Request(thumbNail_url)
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
            data = response.read()        
            thumbPixmap.loadFromData(data)      

            icoLabel = qtw.QLabel()        
            icoLabel.setPixmap(thumbPixmap.scaled(150,150,aspectRatioMode=qtc.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
            self.vid_layout.addWidget(icoLabel)                
        except Exception:
            pass        

        ##right side
        # most upper row: 
        # title
        title = qtw.QLabel(yt_vid.title) 
        self.vidHeaderLayout.addWidget(title) 
              
        self.btn_remove = qtw.QToolButton()        
        self.vidHeaderLayout.addWidget(self.btn_remove)  

        self.vidDetailLayout.addItem(self.vidHeaderLayout)

        # Mid row:
        # Video Specs
        dur_time = yt_vid.length
        duration = qtw.QLabel("Duration: {} sec".format(dur_time))        
        self.vidSpecsLayout.addWidget(duration)   

        self.vidDetailLayout.addItem(self.vidSpecsLayout)

        # mid lower row:
        # Start/End Marker
        self.vidStartEndLayout.setContentsMargins(5,0,5,0)
        self.vidStartEndLayout.setSpacing(10); 
        self.vidStartEndLayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft)        
                        
        vid_start_txt = qtw.QLabel("start at(sec):")        
        vid_start_txt.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft|qtc.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.vidStartEndLayout.addWidget(vid_start_txt)

        lowVal = 0
        self.vid_start = qtw.QLabel(str(lowVal))        
        self.vid_start.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft|qtc.Qt.AlignVCenter)        
        self.vidStartEndLayout.addWidget(self.vid_start)

        vid_end_txt = qtw.QLabel("end at(sec):")        
        vid_end_txt.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft|qtc.Qt.AlignVCenter) 
        self.vidStartEndLayout.addWidget(vid_end_txt)

        highVal = 99
        self.vid_end = qtw.QLabel(str(highVal))   
        
        self.vidStartEndLayout.addWidget(self.vid_end)
        self.vidStartEndLayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft|qtc.Qt.AlignVCenter) 
        self.vidDetailLayout.addItem(self.vidStartEndLayout)

        # lower row:
        # Video specific Buttons (picograms)        
        self.buttonLayout.setSpacing(10); 
        self.buttonLayout.setAlignment(qtc.Qt.AlignLeft)
                
        btn_play = qtw.QToolButton()        
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(btn_play)       

        btn_stop = qtw.QToolButton()
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(btn_stop)    

        btn_download = qtw.QToolButton()      
        self.buttonLayout.addWidget(btn_download)  
        
        self.vidDetailLayout.addItem(self.buttonLayout)
        
        #assamble Layouts and activate it
        self.vid_layout.addItem(self.vidDetailLayout)        
        self.setLayout(self.vid_layout)
    
        return errTxt


class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    
        self.main_window = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.main_window.setupUi(self)        

        self.ytVidODict = OrderedDict()

        self.main_window.insertUrl.clicked.connect(self.insertUrl)

    def insertUrl(self):
        
        if (self.main_window.lineEdit_url.text() == ''):
            return
        else:            
            newUrl = self.main_window.lineEdit_url.text()
            
            if newUrl.strip() in self.ytVidODict:                
                return
            
            #Test URL: Rick Roll https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lrj2Hq7xqQ8      
            #Test URL2: BudS&TerH - Lala Remix: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lL7jwhWAU_k       
            
            item = QYTVidItem(self.main_window.scrollA)              
            returnCode = item.setData(newUrl)            
            if (returnCode == "OK"):                
                row = self.main_window.gridLayout_scroller.count()
                col = 0
                self.main_window.gridLayout_scroller.addWidget(item,row,col,1,1)
                
                #save in OrderedDict:                
                item.btn_remove.clicked.connect(partial(self.removeYTVid,newUrl))
                self.ytVidODict[newUrl.strip()] = item
            else:
                self.main_window.insert_url_msg.setText(returnCode)
                      
            self.main_window.lineEdit_url.setText("")

    def removeYTVid(self,url):               
        #pop from ordered dict
        for vidItem in self.ytVidODict:            
            if vidItem == url.strip():
                self.ytVidODict.pop(url.strip())                
                break            
        
        #clear gridlayout from remaining children
        for i in reversed(range(self.main_window.gridLayout_scroller.count())): 
            widgetToRemove = self.main_window.gridLayout_scroller.itemAt( i ).widget()            
            self.main_window.gridLayout_scroller.removeWidget( widgetToRemove )

        #repopulate gridlayout
        for vidItem in self.ytVidODict:         
            row = self.main_window.gridLayout_scroller.count()
            col = 0
            self.main_window.gridLayout_scroller.addWidget(self.ytVidODict[vidItem],row,col,1,1)            
    
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()

    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `removeWidget` only removes the widget from the layout (so its geometry is no more managed by it) but it still remains a child of the parent. Add `widgetToRemove.deleteLater()` after removing it.

Comment: Besides that, for future reference, try to be more succint in your questions, as your post is *too* detailed and contains a lot of information that is not really useful to the matter. Also, consider that urllib requests are generally blocking, which is something that should **never** happen in a GUI environment. Consider using the QtNetwork module instead (do some research on how to use QNetworkRequest and QNetworkReply).

Comment: thanks musicamante, i will consider your advice and research on the QNetwork module. 
I tested the solution of using the "deleteLater()" function on the widget poped from the ordered dict. Worked perfectly, thanks a lot